# KeyError when using set_index on Dataframe created from read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas

With the following code, I can see the following table output

```
query = f''' SELECT timestamp, base FROM pricing WHERE {timestamp_range} LIMIT {max_records}'''
df: DataFrame = read_sql_query(text(query), db)
print(df.head())
print(df.columns)
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)  # Error here


#  Output
#                    timestamp  base
# 0 2023-02-17 10:25:54.099542    21
# 1 2023-02-17 10:27:54.060627    21
# 2 2023-02-17 10:29:53.581384    22
# 3 2023-02-17 10:31:54.110646    20
# 4 2023-02-17 10:33:53.827830    20
# Index(['timestamp', 'base'], dtype='object')
```

So it looks like I do have the `timestamp` column, but when using `set_index()` I get a `KeyError: 'timestamp'`. Why is this? Using `df.columns[0]` didn't help either.

---

For reference, full stack trace log

```
[2023-02-17 13:50:32,388] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/data/query [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'timestamp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Code/grozd/main.py", line 18, in query
    result = getQuery(request.args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Code/grozd/data.py", line 27, in getQuery
    df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype(int).floordiv(1000000).astype(int)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3807, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'timestamp'
```

Comment: This seems unusual. What version of pandas are you using? Can you post the traceback? Also, does an error occur if you pass `index_col='timestamp'` to `read_sql_query`?

Comment: @Seb Yes same problem occurs when using the read call. Added the trace log. Not sure how I check the version of Pandas but started the project 4 days ago, so I assume latest?

Comment: @ScottBoston Surely that's reading into var `df`, with the type being `DataFrame`?

Comment: What is the encoding used by your DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the traceback it looks like the error does not actually occur in the line you highlighted, but later on when you do this:

```py
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype(int).floordiv(1000000).astype(int)
```

The reason this fails is that once you've assigned the `timestamp` column to the index, it is no longer found among the columns. To fix this you can either perform your transformation first and then set the index, or transform the index directly:

```py
df.index = df.index.astype(int).floordiv(1000000).astype(int)
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, dumb question from me. Thanks mate! This line was working before and in my mind I just assumed the line I just changed was causing the error.